# How safe is it to use webapp2 auth user model in your apps?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

in [webapp-improved](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/) [documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html) states:

> This is an experimental module. The API is subject to changes.

So, my question is - is it safe to use those models in custom applications?

Comment: Have you considered asking this in the webapp2 forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has included it as part of the SDK.  I would say it is plenty secure for most applications.  You are more likely to make a security mistake than the code in Webapp2.  I am using Webapp2 in my applications.